# Docusign C# SDK Unexpected Pem Type

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

Im trying to implement the Docusign sdk and the RequestJWTUserToken method yields an "Unexpected Pem Type" exception. I have copied the private key exactly as it was shown on the docusign admin page.

```
public string JWTAuthLogin()
{
    ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;
    string oAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
    OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(INTEGRATOR_KEY, USER_ID, oAuthBasePath, PRIVATE_KEY_BYTES, 1);
    OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token);
    string accountId = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in userInfo.Accounts)
    {
        if (item.IsDefault == "true")
        {
            accountId = item.AccountId;
            apiClient = new ApiClient(item.BaseUri + "/restapi");
            break;
        }
    }
    return accountId;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

ssee here https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/168 how some people resolved this issue:

**Solution 1:**

```
var privateKeyStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(testConfig.PrivateKeyFilename));
    OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(testConfig.clientId, testConfig.UserId, testConfig.OAuthBasePath, privateKeyStream, testConfig.ExpiresInHours);
```

**Solution 2:**

Install the DocuSign.eSign.dll nuget package and then:

```
        _apiClient ??= new ApiClient();
        this._authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
            this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ClientId"],
            this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:ImpersonatedUserId"],
            this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:AuthServer"],
            DSHelper.ReadFileContent(DSHelper.PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(this._configuration["DocuSignJWT:PrivateKeyFile"])), 1, scopes);
        _account = GetAccountInfo(_authToken);
```

You will have to have your IK, your userId and the file that you're reading from.

Here is the DSHelper methods:

```
    internal static byte[] ReadFileContent(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    }
    internal static string PrepareFullPrivateKeyFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        const string DefaultRSAPrivateKeyFileName = "docusign_private_key.txt";

    var fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNameOnly))
    {
        fileNameOnly = DefaultRSAPrivateKeyFileName;
    }

    var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }

    return Path.Combine(filePath, fileNameOnly);
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 didn't work... it caused the same PEM error message
Solution 2.. There's not enough context to understand what PrivateKeyFilename is supposed to do.